# Better understanding of MySQL uppercase letters on query

Tags: mysql

I'm new to PDO & MySQL in general. I'm switching from the soon to be deprecated MySQL to PDO, I have some questions to better understand how MySQL querying works.

I currently have this function, I don't understand the meaning of the uppercase U. & M. before the table rows.

Are the M. connected to the $morequery = ""; & U. to the Updates function?

```
public function Updates( $_iD, $lastid ){
$morequery = " "; // More Button
$data = " ";

if( $lastid )
    $morequery = "AND M.post_iD < '".$lastid."' "; // More Button End
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT M.post_iD, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, U._iUsername,M.uploads FROM Posts M, users U  WHERE U._iStatus='1' AND M.uid_fk=U._iD and M.uid_fk='$_iD' $morequery order by M.post_iD desc limit" .$this->perpage) or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                $data[] = $row;
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: What I don't understand here is why are you still using `mysql_query` in the example? Didn't you say you're converting to `PDO`? Also, check @Explosion Pills's answer - your question has nothing to do with `PHP` and `PDO`. It is `MySQL` related. So please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PHP or PDO specifically, but only MySQL.  `U` and `M` are table aliases created in the `FROM` clause:

```
FROM Posts M, users U
```

This means that throughout the query, `M` is a reference to that `Posts` table.  You can specify the table of a column to select (`Posts.post_ID` would work were it not aliased).

This is necessary when two tables you are querying have the same column name.  For example, there may be an ambiguity between `M.uid_fk` and `U.uid_fk`.  If there is no ambiguity, it's not necessary and may be done simply for clarity.

Such an ambiguity may arise by joining on the same table twice.  In that case, at least one alias is necessary anyway because the tables themselves become ambiguous.

Comment: That's a great clarification of my question, as @FriederikeS suggested, great indepth explanation. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The U & M are table alias

If you look at the from clause of the statement (`FROM Posts M, users U`) that is where they are defined

M = Posts

U = users

For this case you can substitute the U's with users and the M with Posts in get the same results.

On simple queries it is a helpful shorthand, on queries where a table joins to itself it is needed to resolve any ambiguity

Comment: As @Orangepill stated, these are aliases to the table names. What he has missed to state is they're used to shorten table names with long names or in case you have to `JOIN` on the same table.

Comment: Thank you for the great and simple explanation!

Answer (score 0):

M and U are shortcuts for the table names:

```
FROM Posts M, users U
```